# Xamarin Studio bug when copy file in Assets folder

Tags: android, xamarin, textview, xamarin.android

I am Creating `RobotoTextView` When I add `.ttf` file to Assets Folder. The below error is error :

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:
>   Error: Cannot copy
>   /Users/BizSalt/Projects/Gargi/Gargi.Droid/Assets/fonts/ to
>   /Users/BizSalt/Projects/Gargi/Gargi.Droid/obj/Debug/assets/fonts/, as
>   the source file doesn't exist. (Gargi.Droid)

I try to clean and Rebuild Project. and also Restart the Xamarin Studio but nothing get success.

Any help be Appreciated ??

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the `.ttf` file is in the Assets folder - is it set to `Build Action: AndroidAsset` as well?

How are you accessing the font when assigning it to the TextView?

I think [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/62164/using-custom-fonts-in-android) thread on the Xamarin forums will be of further use to help diagnose your issue without knowing more about what you're doing.

Comment: in that `Thread` if you read the `james` Answer and go to it's link. there are add `.ttf` file in `Assets` Folder that why this bug is happen ?

Comment: @Ironman That's why I'm asking if you've checked the build action on the file?